# http request to google returning empty python socket

Tags: python, sockets, request

im trying to send an http request to google, but all I receive is empty (b""). Here is my code:

```py
import socket

target_host = "www.google.com"

target_port = 80
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

client.connect((target_host, target_port))
print("Connected...")


request = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:%s\r\n\r\n" % target_host

response = client.recv(4096)
http_response = repr(response)
http_response_len = len(http_response)

print("[+RECV+] - length %d" % http_response_len)
print(http_response)
```

Here is my response:

```
[+RECV+] - length 3
b''
```

(also it took like 240 seconds to complete the request, is that normal?)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I forgot to send the data with

```py
client.send(request.encode())
```